# QEMU warning SDL 1.2 is deprecated

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, sdl

Starting QEMU in a terminal with

> qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -m 6G -smp cores=3 -cpu host -drive file=...

produces the following warning:

> Running QEMU with SDL 1.2 is deprecated, and will be removed
>   in a future release. Please switch to SDL 2.0 instead

Question How do I "switch" to SDL 2.0? Simply installing libsdl2-2.0 package doesn't change anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore this warning.

It means that Qemu in your version of Ubuntu was compiled against SDL 1.2, which is deprecated (but still functional). In future versions Qemu must be compiled against SDL 2.0 instead.

This is something that the Ubuntu package maintainers must do (and in fact already have in 18.10, apparently by removing SDL support). There is no action that you need to take.

You can add `-display gtk` to get rid of the warning and also get better performance than SDL would have offered.

Comment: Understood - but what triggers the warning? Is it simply the fact that QEMU is compiuled with SDL 1.2 or is it triggered by the use of a certein command upon invocation?

Comment: @mgw As I said in the answer, it is because qemu was compiled against SDL 1.2. You will see the warning if you ask for SDL graphics. Try `-display gtk` to get rid of the warning and get a better more performant display.

Answer (score 0):

If you made qemu from source(https://download.qemu.org/), try installing SDL2.0 via https://gist.github.com/Vinatorul/4b3ca4c1b96c18b110db and `./configure; make; sudo make install` again in your qemu directory.